# sid = request.POST.get['stuid'] TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable

Tags: javascript, python, ajax

this is my view code in django for saving data and sid is for editing the User id data if it not blank then it will be edited else it is store as a new id .

```py
def save_data(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = StudentRegistration(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            sid = request.POST.get['stuid']
            name = request.POST['name']
            email = request.POST['email']
            password = request.POST['password']
            if (sid == ''):
                usr = User(name=name,email=email,password=password)
            else:
                usr = User(id = sid ,name= name,email= email, password= password)
            usr.save()
            stud = User.objects.values()
            print(stud)
            student_data = list(stud)
            return JsonResponse({'status':'Save','student_data':student_data})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'status':0})
```

Answer (score 0):

`get` is a method, so the brackets to invoke that method should be parentheses:

```
 request.POST.get('stuid')
```

Answer (score -1):

every method, so the brackets to invoke that method should be parentheses:
request`enter code here`.POST.get('your_id')

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).